# Cordova Push Plugin on Android not working when app is closed or not running

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, push-notification

I've been trying to use this plugin for push notification in my app.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/

And send push by Node-GCM. Everything works perfectly when the app is in foreground and in background (Background = when user tap home button).

The only problem is Notification is not showing when the app is closed or not running. If user close the app by force stop from Setting > Apps or slip the app away to terminate the app task.

I've been finding the solutions for this. But still can't solve this. Is there anyone here having experience of this and can solve it? I didn't change any code of the plugin and following the example client code from Plugin's Github. Please help me solve this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, I opened an issue but haven't found anything helpful to get it working yet

Comment: Hello Dan. This is very important. Push message while the app is not running will remind user about the app very well. As i've noticed, Facebook app will never completely stopped even thought we force stop it. It's still running when we check at Setting > Apps > Running. I'm not sure we need to modify something in the app to make it always run like Facebook. What's your idea?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this yet? I am seeing the same issue.  It's worth noting that the same app works fine with iOS.  I get the notifications even when the app is closed, just not on Android.

Comment: All I kjnow is that applications that are running when app is closed is because they are running a service.
You should see this plugin https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

Comment: you need to run broadcast reciver service in your case

Answer (score 0):

Does your notification have a "message"?  Like this: {\"message\":\"Hello World!\",\"sound\":\"beep.wav\"}

That was my problem.  I figured it out after reading this article:  http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_pushplugin_background_notifications_dont_seem_to_work

Answer (score 0):

For what I've been reading, there are 3 running modes.

1. **Foreground**: when you are using the application.
2. **Background**: when you have the application minimized but not closed and you can restore it where you left it before minimizing.
3. **Back-background**: when you have closed your application but there are a service generated by the application that is listening some specific events (i.e. waiting push notifications).

When you are in the modes 1 and 2, your application can receive push notifications because the PushPlugin is running but, when you are in mode 3, the plugin will fail because the application is not running, you have to create the service that will be waiting for notifications or what you want.

This is what Whatsapp application is doing for example.

Here you can see a pluggin for AppGyver that does implements a service:

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core